# Bitbucket pipelines - How to count number of commits

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to use Bitbucket pipelines and create a tag concatenated with the total amount of commits.
I tried many syntax's but for some reason I can't make it work properly.The commits number won't change even though I committed something to the Bitbucket.

This is what I tried:

```
 - git rev-list --all --remotes
 - git rev-list --simplify-by-decoration -500000 HEAD | wc -l
 - git rev-list HEAD | wc -l
 - git rev-list HEAD --count --first-parent
```

How would you accomplish it?
Also when I run the same git commands on my machine I get different number of commits.

Thanks

Comment: I suspect pipelines limit the number of commits to clone using `git clone --depth=<number>`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for that.
https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/configure-bitbucket-pipelinesyml/

The reason is that BitBucket by default clones with depth 50.

I added this code:`clone: depth: full`

and It solved it